# Coloring text in terminal according to part of speech

Tags: python, nltk, colorama

I'd like to color the sentence in terminal so that nouns will be blue and verbs will be green. Everything else will be black.

So far, i tried to use `nltk` and `colorama` modules for this purpose.

```
import nltk
from colorama import Fore
```

This code will find out the nouns and verbs, so that verbs are `VB` or `VBD` and nouns are `NN`.

```
s = nltk.word_tokenize(sample_sentence)
tagged_text = nltk.pos_tag(s)
print tagged_text

[('Stately', 'RB'), (',', ','), ('plump', 'VB'), ('Buck', 'NNP'), ('Mulligan', 'NNP'), ('came', 'VBD'), ('from', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('stairhead', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('bearing', 'VBG'), ('a', 'DT'), ('bowl', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('lather', 'NN'), ('on', 'IN'), ('which', 'WDT'), ('a', 'DT'), ('mirror', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'), ('razor', 'NN'), ('lay', 'NN'), ('crossed', 'VBD'), ('.', '.')]
```

When I want to print colored text I will use:

```
print Fore.BLUE + some_noun
print Fore.GREEN + some_verb
print Fore.BLACK + something_else
```

I have a problem to print the sentence. How would you loop through `tagged_text` so that it will print the `sample_sentence` unchanged (only the desired colors will be applied)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? It keeps the whitespace exactly as in the original text. I do believe verbs ought to be red though.

```
from colorama import Fore, init
import re
init()

tagged_text = [('Stately', 'RB'), (',', ','), ('plump', 'VB'), ('Buck', 'NNP'), ('Mulligan', 'NNP'), ('came', 'VBD'),
                ('from', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('stairhead', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('bearing', 'VBG'), ('a', 'DT'), 
                ('bowl', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('lather', 'NN'), ('on', 'IN'), ('which', 'WDT'), ('a', 'DT'),
                ('mirror', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'),('razor', 'NN'), ('lay', 'NN'), ('crossed', 'VBD'),
                ('.', '.'), ('The', 'DET'), ('function', 'NN'), ('f', 'SYM'), ('(','('),('x','SYM'),(',',','),
                ('y','SYM'),(')',')'),('takes','VB'), ('two', 'CD'), ('arguments', 'NN'), ('.','.')]
origtext = 'Stately, plump Buck Mulligan came from the stairhead, bearing a bowl of lather on which a mirror and a razor lay crossed. The function f(x,y) takes two arguments.'

colordict = {'VB': Fore.GREEN, 'VBD': Fore.GREEN, 'NN': Fore.BLUE}

colorwords = ''
for word, tag in tagged_text:
    color = Fore.BLACK
    word = re.match(r'\s*%s\s*' % re.escape(word), origtext).group()
    origtext = origtext.split(word,1)[1]
    if tag in colordict:
        color = colordict[tag]
    colorwords += color + word

print colorwords
```

Comment: Here, every word is on a new line. The sentence should be printed as the original sentence, only colored.

Comment: @xralf If you add a comma after a print statement, it will be printed on the same line. `print "Cow say MOO!!",`

Comment: @CoffeeRain I know, but the sentence won't be the same (there will be more undesired whitespace before punctuation)

Comment: @Junuxx It's not so easy. The sentence can be like `The function f(a, b) takes two arguments.`

Comment: @xralf: That's not exactly plump Buck Mulligan, is it? You should give a better example, because it is not evident how `f(a, b) would be tokenized. One or two regex substitutions should still easily fix this though.

Comment: @Junuxx The whitespace in original sentence (sampleSentence) should not change, but you're right - the sentence is not correctly tokenized too, so incorrect colors will be applied, but I'd like to preserve the whitespace too. Note, that the first sentence is also not correctly tokenized (e.g. the word `lay`).

Comment: @xralf: No, the tokenization of lay is fine, although it is tagged incorrectly. See the solution for the whitespace issue in the (again) updated code. Colorama's color characters are applied to matched words plus their surrounding whitespace from the original text.

Comment: OK, I accepted the answer. btw. I noticed that the POS tagger is pretty unreliable, so my idea and snippet is worthless in the end.

Comment: @xralf: That's because you use the shortcut nltk.pos_tag, which uses a rubbish corpus (Wall Street Journal - completely unrepresentative of normal English). Read sections 5.4-5.6 of [this](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html) and try a better corpus. Good luck!